# Python: How to sort a list by the count of specific character

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a program that orders a list of strings based on the count of specific character, which is dot `.`

`['C222.', 'C4444', 'C22..', 'C333.', 'C2222']`are how my list is imported, but I need to put them like this:

```
['C2222', 'C4444', 'C333.', 'C222.', 'C22..']
```

I don't care how items are sorted if they have the same number of dots

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with a key function checking the count of specified character:

```
>>> lst = ['C222.', 'C4444', 'C22..', 'C333.', 'C2222']
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda t: t.count("."))
['C4444', 'C2222', 'C222.', 'C333.', 'C22..']
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: oh, best approach, I will look to the key documentation!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach with `numpy`:

```
np.array(ll)[np.argsort([i.count('.') for i in ll])].tolist()
#['C4444', 'C2222', 'C222.', 'C333.', 'C22..']
```